# Terms that representing a filtered tags

Tags: abbreviations, symbols

On my webpage I'm trying to filter search results, using tags. Very much so like here.

Now suppose I have three tags that I've selected.

I show three options in the web page.

```
Option1: Search Results that have **all** three tags.
Option2: Search Results that **any 1** or all of the three tags.
Option3: Search Results that have **NO** tags at all.
```

The terms I use to represent the above options is simply:

```
1. Tags
2. Any Tags
3. No Tags.
```

This is where I think I'm completely wrong in my language usage. Is there anything I can do to improve the above buttons?

They don't effectively convey the option they represent.

My question is, what else can I use instead of **Tags**, **Any Tags** etc..

Should I be using symbols of some kind?

Comment: All Tags, Some Tags, No Tags seem closer. You could even leave off Tags in a pinch.

Comment: Yea, I think. But if i leave off `Tags`, what should I use? "All", "Any" ? "Combined" or something. Suppose If i attempted to create a small icon, again i don't know how I would represent it.

Answer (score 1):

I think adding the words Include and Exclude will make it clear what you plan on doing with the user's selections.

```
Include all tags: ________  
Include any tag: ________  
Exclude all tags: ________
```

Comment: Hey thanks for replying. Can you suggesting something shorter? I don't know myself but something like "Tags+" Tags-" I really don't know what is appropriate here.

Comment: Shortest I can offer is "Include all", "Include any", and "Exclude all"